# How to get EntityManager in class using abstract classes

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an abstract class like

```
class Importer
{
    public static function getInstance($url)
    {

    }

    protected function saveUser(User $user)
    {
        //here I want to use doctrine to save persist my User Entity
    }           
}
```

and another class that extends that one

```
class XmlImporter extends Importer()
{
    public function processUser()
    {
         //do something with my data
         parent::processUser($user);
    }
}
```

pretty much standard situation. The problem is in saveUser I need to save my user on db (I am using mongo), so, how can I get the entity manager? I thougth I could use a service but I don't know where to receive it, in the child class or in the parent? Any other best practice I could follow.

thanks

Comment: Doctrine's entity manager is based on what is known as a data mapper.  Your question shows an active record approach.  You should probably spend some time researching how Doctrine works or substitute an active record based component.

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad architecture if you need to get entity manager in your entity. Entity is the object like associated array. Everything what it need to do is to control internal properties. Entities can be used in different managers.

It will be better if you will create another service layer to control entities.

For example:

```
class User 
{

    /* @ORM ... */
    private $id
    /* @ORM ... */
    private $name

    public function getId() {...}
    public function setName($name) {...}
    public function getName() {...}

    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf(
            'User [id: %s, name: "%s"',
            $this->getId() ? $this->getId() : '-',
            $this->getName()
        )
    }

}

class UserModel
{

    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManagerForClass('AppBundle:User');
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        return $em;
    }

    protected function validatePersistFlush(User $user)
    {
        // validate
        $errors = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($user);
        if (count($errors)) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf(
                '%s is not valid: %s',
                $user,
                (string)$errors
            ));
        }

        // persist
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user);

        // flush
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush($user);

    }

    public function create($name)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setName($name);
        $this->validatePersistFlush($user)
        return $user;
    }

    public rename(User $user, $newName)
    {
        $user->setName($newName);
        $this->validatePersistFlush($user)
        return $user;        
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, I made some mess with classes names in my example, I amended it. Of course they are not Entities and I am not going to use doctrine inside entities. Just wanted to understand how to get mongodb doctrine in a class using a sort of factory pattern. thanks.